# How to forward postfix event logging to an http endpoint?

Tags: ubuntu, postfix, rsyslog

I would like to monitor postfix with a tool I wrote my self, I need to do it live right after sending, my optimal solution will be somehow make postfix send it's events to a logging system other then rsyslog I am running now, and have this system post to an http url that is local/ or not to the machine, this way I can get the logs realtime on my system

Is there a way to force postfix to this kind of scenario

I am on Ubuntu 12.04

Comment: _rsyslog_ can use a named pipe (fifo) as a destination. If your tool is creates the fifo and listens on it, and you configure _rsyslog_ to send _postfix_ entries to that destination, this will probably be your easiest and cleanest solution. Note that the fifo must be created before _rsyslog_ starts.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Postfix uses the system's syslog facility.
Whatever that allows you to do, you can use.